# Google maps doesn't work in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, internet-explorer

I call my HTML with googlemaps from another application by window.open (javascript). The html page open, but dont works (any action fails), i just can see the map. After i do CTRL + f5 works... I need this working in the first call... someone can help me?

html:

```
    <html>
    <body>

    <h1>Prisma3 x Google Maps</h1>

    <div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>

    <script>

    function myMap() {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
        zoom: 3,
        center: {lat: 0, lng: -180},
        mapTypeId: 'terrain'
    });

    var flightPlanCoordinates = [
        {lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214},
        {lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821},
        {lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431},
        {lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027}
    ];

    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: flightPlanCoordinates,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
    });

    flightPath.setMap(map);
}

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
    key=AIzaSyC7vePTtjVs90u3kKlOMYP-UtyISm9F56M&callback=myMap"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: When something fails in Google Maps you normally get error messages in the console. Have you checked that?

Comment: And you also go to the docs and carefully checked which browsers are supported.

Comment: I see a map with the posted code in IE11 on the first load (don't see the polyline though).  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced your key with my own and your code(with the javascript at the bottom) works on both Firefox and Internet Explorer.

I had a similar problem recently and below was my solution:

1.0 Asuming you are already logged-in to Gmail, visit 
https://console.developers.google.com

2.0 You will land at API Manager

3.0 Under Google Maps API, choose Google Maps JavaScript API

4.0 At Google Maps JavaScript API, there is a link at the top named ENABLE

5.0 Click it to enable or activate the API.

Hope it helps

Comment: I just like to add that I tested your code online, at my Host. Since my key is restricted to my domain name.

Comment: Aaah sorry. There was one other thing which I did and it came from this tutorial https://churchthemes.com/page-didnt-load-google-maps-correctly/  as stated on point 3. This will help if you restricted your key to your domain name. But just still go through it because all the various errors are described in there.