# Google maps error Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I know it's been discussed here many times - but unfortunately i'm experiencing some issues with google maps and the solutions here do not works for me....

For start - i get 'google is not defined' error with no apparent reason. The code works fine but then after doing some minor changes and then refresh - i get the error.
After the error appears it's takes about a day for the API to work again... I've checked  [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits) but i don't comes near 2,500 requests a day.....

My structure is very basic...

First:

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

Then:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=SOME-KEY&callback=initMap">
```

Then :

```
 function initMap() {

      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    });
 }
  initMap()
```

I've tried to switch between the places of the link... but it did nothing...

Comment: Remove the `initMap` call from your code.  It is being called before the library is finished loading (and that function is the callback function when the library finishes loading.

Comment: geocodezip  - Thanks, but it didn't worked... as i said - the code works fine - but after a couple of refreshes - it's kind of stucks...

Comment: It fixes the issue for me in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6yd83gkw/1/).  If it doesn't work for you, please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: I've used my key and tested your code online. No changes to it. It works. Solution is likely going to be here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44801609/google-maps-doesnt-work-in-internet-explorer-11/44802835?noredirect=1#comment76587181_44802835 There is an important link in the comment to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have already initMap in you script calling google maps so you should not add  th initMap() in inner script .  try comment the initMap(); as :

```
function initMap() {

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
  zoom: 8
});
}
//initMap()
```